# Why can't an iterator return a concrete data type?

Tags: java, typing

In Java, why can't iterator return a concrete data type.
For example:

```
//access via Iterator
Iterator iterator = queueA.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext(){
    String element = (String) iterator.next();
}
```

I have to cast it to `String` explicitly. 
Why cannot an iterator return `String` automatically?

Comment: What version of Java are you compiling against? Java 1.5 (or 5) and higher support [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and you can do `Iterator<String>` if your `queueA`'s iterator method returns a generic `Iterator` typed for `String`.

Comment: It can return a concrete type. You seem to have missed the fact that Generics were introduced into Java, [over ten years ago](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/codenames-136090.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterator is a generic class, just like Queue. You should declare your iterator as such:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = new queueA.iterator();
```

Comment: oh i see. So, is my code bad practice?

Comment: If your Java version is 1.5 (which is when generics were added) or higher, yes I'd say so. The point of generics is to avoid casting.